# repeat a value of a row in a new column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've this table with the following data

```
id    Product     Price 
1      ELECTRO     TV
2      null       null
3      null       null
4      Samsung    1000
5      LG         2000
6      Philips    1300
7      ELECTRO    Mobile
8      null       null
9      null       null
10     Samsung    1000
11     Nokia      2000
12     Sony       1300
```

I need to add another column and repeat the value the resultant table should be as below:

```
    id    Product     Price     Category
    1      ELECTRO     TV         TV
    2      null       null        TV
    3      null       null        TV
    4      Samsung    1000        TV
    5      LG         2000        TV
    6      Philips    1300        TV
    7      ELECTRO    Mobile      Mobile
    8      null       null        Mobile
    9      null       null        Mobile
    10     Samsung    1000        Mobile
    11     Nokia      2000        Mobile
    12     Sony       1300        Mobile
```

Can someone please help me out with this query? because i don't have any idea how can i do it

Comment: What is the size of the table? what are the nulls for? if there are more rows? are they always with the same format as 6 per category? do you need this to alter the table or just want the select query to return this?

Comment: the format can be change just i need a select query to return the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a235/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id, Product, Price ) AS
          SELECT 1,  'ELECTRO', 'TV'     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,  null,      null     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,  null,      null     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,  'Samsung', '1000'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,  'LG',      '2000'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,  'Philips', '1300'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7,  'ELECTRO', 'Mobile' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8,  null,      null     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9,  null,      null     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'Samsung', '1000'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'Nokia',   '2000'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'Sony',    '1300'   FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       PRODUCT,
       PRICE,
       CASE PRODUCT
         WHEN 'ELECTRO' THEN PRICE
         ELSE LAG( CASE PRODUCT WHEN 'ELECTRO' THEN PRICE END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY ID )
         END AS CATEGORY
FROM   test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a235/2/0)**:

```
| ID | PRODUCT |  PRICE | CATEGORY |
|----|---------|--------|----------|
|  1 | ELECTRO |     TV |       TV |
|  2 |  (null) | (null) |       TV |
|  3 |  (null) | (null) |       TV |
|  4 | Samsung |   1000 |       TV |
|  5 |      LG |   2000 |       TV |
|  6 | Philips |   1300 |       TV |
|  7 | ELECTRO | Mobile |   Mobile |
|  8 |  (null) | (null) |   Mobile |
|  9 |  (null) | (null) |   Mobile |
| 10 | Samsung |   1000 |   Mobile |
| 11 |   Nokia |   2000 |   Mobile |
| 12 |    Sony |   1300 |   Mobile |
```

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be a number of things wrong with the design of your data here, and I really think that you need to address them before trying to make your query. For starters, it looks like Electro is a category, and should therefore be a column, but Product is already doing the work, which makes Electro in any form look redundant. If Electro is somehow not redundant, it should have it's own column.

Your rows containing null are also a symptom that something is almost certainly wrong with your data design, as it would seem unlikely that you have a TV with both no manufacturer and no price.

Additionally you appear to have mixed numeric and character data in the Price column: again suggesting that there is a serious flaw in the data design.

I don't think that you can really get the outcome you want to achieve given the data you appear to have, and to me it looks as if your underlying data needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what value to assign to the each row (either TV or Mobile)?

But avoiding that "little" detail, you first need to add a column with an ALTER statement:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTVAndMobileData
ADD Category varchar2(15);
```

And then update all of the rows with UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE yourTVAndMobileData
SET Category = DECODE ( id, ( SELECT m.id 
                                  FROM Mobiles m 
                                  WHERE m.id=id; ), "Mobile",
                            "TV" );
```

I have assumed you have a table Mobiles with a column "id" which is a foreign key for your table of all devices. Change this logic as it suits you.

I *think* this should work. Let me know if it doesn't...

Comment: Hi thanks for reply what i need just a select statement

Comment: You cannot create a new column and update the values of rows with a _SELECT_ statement. Or maybe I didn't understand you quite well?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH src AS (
SELECT 1 ID  , 'ELECTRO' Product, 'TV' Price FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2     , null      , null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3     , null      , null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4     , 'Samsung'   , '1000'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5     , 'LG'        , '2000'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6     , 'Philips'   , '1300'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7     , 'ELECTRO'   , 'Mobile'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8     , null      , null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9     , null      , null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10    , 'Samsung'   , '1000'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11    , 'Nokia'     , '2000'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12    , 'Sony'      , '1300'  FROM DUAL)
SELECT
    src.*,
    LAST_VALUE(NVL2(TRIM(TRANSLATE(price, '0123456789', ' ')), price, null)) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY ID) category
FROM
    src;
```

But agreed that your data structure doesn't look good.